# How to search for a folder or file in parent folders

Tags: find, search, recursive

I tried to search for a folder in its parent folders instead of its child sub-folders (usually any search bash command will do). I need to know whether any reverse alternative for any search commands actually exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "using find . -iname in reverse order"?  I don't understand, either, what a "reverse alternative" would be. Could you give some examples?

Comment: What is expected behavior of that ? If you can search through all parent folders you can search from / as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry, i would have referred to it better. All i need to know, is there any possibility to search for a folder or file or any content in parent directories rather than searching it in its child sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in a parent directory you should use "../" as the path. And then exclude the folder you are in.

Maybe something linke this? (Assume that you are in "currentfolder" when running the command.

```
find ../ -iname "file" -not -path "../currentfolder/*"
```

This will search the parent folder and subfolders in those.
I kinda think the best way is to seach from the top, and im not sure there are other ways.

Comment: And of course use "-type d" to find folders and not files.

Comment: For example, if I wanna search for .hg or .git folder (if it is a cloned repository) and I don't have any clear idea about which folder under those folders reside. Then how do I know how deep I have to go backwards?!

Comment: Why not search from the top? Like searching from "/" or "/var/www/". You must have some idea what top folder the folders are located in.